# Is it possible to prove that an elephant and a human could jump to the same height?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, biology, scaling

Is there a physics argument, based on scaling, that leads to the conclusion that an elephant and a human could jump about same height?

Could this be extended to any two creatures with different masses?

Comment: A conversation about the on-topic-ness of this question has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74450/discussion-on-question-by-quantumcasanova-is-it-possible-to-prove-that-an-elepha); while that conversation was taking place, an [identical question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391954/44126) started to get answers.